# Создание указателя в lua ffi

Tags: lua, serial

Я в lua `ffi` пытаюсь считать все байты из serial порта при помощи `read` из `C`. Однако, указатель на буфер по ходу чтения перемещается (`buf = buf + n`). В результате, я получаю только последнее считывание в буфере.

Как я понимаю, необходимо создать ещё один указатель на буфер. Но как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, буфер вы создаёте как-то так (обратите внимание на звёзодочку):

```
local buf = ffi.new('char*[?]', size)
```

В таком случае, указатель на `buf` следует создавать вот таким образом:

```
local fullbuf = ffi.cast('char*', buf)
```

Примечание: простое присвоение

```
local fullbuf = buf
```

не прокатит, т. к. `cdata` является обычным `userdata`, следовательно, имеет идентичность, и `fullbuf` также изменится вместе с `buf`.

Comment: Это перевод с англоязычной версии SO? Не плохо бы оставить ссылку на оригинал.

Comment: @zed: эээ... Я не переводил, на самом деле.

Comment: Т.е. это вы так сам с собой разговариваете? _"Я в lua ffi пытаюсь..."_ а потом _"Как я понимаю, буфер вы создаёте как-то так"_ Я ничего против не имею, просто показалось, что это взято откуда-то.

Comment: @zen: ну да, общаюсь с умным человеком :)